# Stacked bar issue with new version of plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to make a very simple bar chart with ggplot2 and then to turn it into interactive graph with the ggplotly function from the plotly package. 
The final graph looks ok, but the values rendered in the hover text are not good. Actually, it renders stacked values instead of individual values.

Here is a reproducible example :

```
#data
dataf = data.frame(Espece = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                   Type = c("A","B","A","B","A","B"),
                   Value = c(2,2,5,1,6,0))
#ggplot
gg = ggplot(dataf, aes(x = Espece, y = Value, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

#plotly
p <- ggplotly(gg)
p
```

[image]

As you can see on the picture, the value for Espece A, type B is 4 whereas it should be 2.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: You use `dataf2` in ggplot while creating `dataf` just before. Is `dataf2` a new data frame or equal to `dataf` ? In `dataf`, the value for Espece A, type B is 4.

Answer (score 0):

When you print the ggplot graphic it looks fine. So maybe it's one of the bugs. Until it's fixed maybe you could use this alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
datafA <- dataf %>% filter(Type == "A")
datafB <- dataf %>% filter(Type == "B")

p <- plot_ly(data=datafA,
  x = Espece,
  y = Value,
  type = "bar",
  hoverinfo="text",
  text = paste("Espece = ", datafA$Espece, "<br>Value = ", datafA$Value, "<br>Type = ", datafA$Type),
  color = Type, colors = "red"
)
p


p2 <- add_trace(
  p,
  data=datafB,
  x = Espece,
  y = Value,
  type = "bar",
  hoverinfo="text",
  text = paste("Espece = ", datafB$Espece, "<br>Value = ", datafB$Value, "<br>Type = ", datafB$Type),
  color = Type, colors = "blue"
)
p2

layout(p2, barmode = "stack", showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @MLavoie, thank you very much for your answer.
I thought about that solution but the thing is, it was just an exemple, in the real data, I have various number of categories, from 10 to 50.
It seems a little bit tricky to use the add_trace for each category. I would prefer to use the ggplotly function. Do you think it's an actual bug or just me using this function the wrong way ?

Comment: I think it's a bug. It happens frequently :(